Is it unprofessional to blindly follow the management ideas? (if that's the company culture)
I'm a senior software engineer with a good understanding of the business.
My manager has a business focus and comes with requests that are clearly not feasible.
I have a good list of records that my past predictions about the feasibility of a feature was correct.
However, my company doesn't reward technical expertise and prefers people blindly following the management ideas.
Question:
When I receive a request from my boss, is it unprofessional to blindly follow the request?

Don't follow blindly. Do follow until you understand the rationale -- remember that they have usually been doing this longer than you have, and that technical decisions and business decisions don't always agree. Yes, it is unprofessional not to try your best to make the idea work while suggesting and justifying alternatives.

@Fe2O3: I'm not sure to understand your question. My question is how to handle this in a professional manner, not asking where this issue is not present. Would you mind clarifying if I misunderstood you?

Please clarify: What exactly happens if you do blindly follow such a request for something that is not feasible? If it truly is not feasible, it seems you should be ending up with no result - how do your higher-ups react to this eventual outcome?

As a professional, it is part of your job to advise your boss, about potential pitfalls, dangers, practicality and time taken.  If your boss insists and you still think that it is a bad idea then you either look for another job or you swallow your professionalism and do as you are told.  In the latter case, it will still come back to bite you as you will be blamed for the problems.  If you really want to go down this path then you should document it via email.
Here are two examples from my career, both working for a large multi-national company.  There were many more incidents, where I took a stand - because it was my job as an expert in that field to do so.

A major lift company approached us and wanted to computerise (in the 1980s).  They wanted the microprocessor to accept all inputs and control all outputs.  I asked "What about the fail-safe that is normally installed in the lifts (in the form of friction clamps)".  They said that it wasn't necessary as the microprocessor would handle it.  I could foresee drastic fatal accidents.  I was only a project Engineer at this stage.  I told my boss that "I wanted nothing to do with it.  If he felt he had to fire me, that was fine.".  To my surprise he told them that them that our company would not do the job.

We used to program in Pascal on CPM/M.  A major company insisted that we use Informix and C on Unix for their project.  By this time I was the manager of the project division. I told my boss that this project was going to lose money.  However, I wanted additional resources to try and mitigate that.  He allowed me to fly over an expert from USA and train 7 of us in C and Informix.  I also bought all available books and videos at that time.  Unfortunately the project still made a loss, but only a minor one.



Lift = elevator, yes?

@DanielR.Collins No, elevator = lift :-)

TL;DR: Don't do it blindly. Do it because that's what you are being paid to do.
Addressing the question that was asked rather than the complaints that went with it:
As a professional, you are certainly expected to provide polite feedback to your manager -- preferably with a business case -- on whether a proposed approach is the best available option or not.
As a professional, you are then expected to accept your manager's direction and do what the business wants, the way the business wants it done, when the business wants it done, with the priority and urgency that the business has assigned it.
If you can't make a good enough case for doing something different to convince management, you probably don't understand their needs well enough, or you don't understand your own suggestion well enough. In which case you do it their way.
Re having been right in the past: Beware confirmation bias in your memory of your success rate, and remember that "right" in retrospect may still have legitimately been wrong at the time given the needs of the time.
Part of being a pro is learning how to do your best work even on things you don't agree with, and learning how to explain your disagreements in a positive manner.

As the business aware person, your manager is supposed to have a grip on the value of this work. And as senior software engineer, you should have a grip on the cost of the work.
It would be obvious that you check it, report the cost of the work as it is proposed, check for things that might be removed because they add very little value but a lot of cost, and make suggestions about things that add very little cost but might be of value.
If the company does this right, then they can easily end up with more value at less cost. The other way round if they don't do it right; seems your company is in that category. So what do they do to avoid cost? The manager who doesn't know about it makes it up? It's much more efficient if they manager can ask for anything he thinks may be useful, and you tell him what it costs.


When I receive a request from my boss, is it unprofessional to blindly
follow the request?

It's not clear what "blindly" means in this context.
It's your professional responsibility to analyze every request, provide a reasoned response regarding feasibility and alternatives, then to carry out the subsequent (perhaps modified) request to the best of your ability.
If the time frame seems infeasible, after providing feedback you learn the priorities of the tasks so that your focus is on the most important tasks.
If a technical aspect of a request appears infeasible, suggest a pilot process or suggest an alternative. Then do your best to implement whatever approach management chooses.

The shorter version of what the other answers are politely saying is that if you value being valued consider moving on.
If a management team doesn't value smart people having smart ideas, they will be left behind by the competition.
This doesn't mean to say to become an annoying steamroller, but when you can add value, bring it to the team. Don't expect that every idea will be used. But most should be considered.

Short Answer, No - it is not unprofessional
Longer Answer:
There is a lot of Nuance here and I will try and thread the needle as best I can. I want to start with an extreme example to make my point: Have we tried Kill all the Poor?
(obvious disclaimer - I am not suggesting a Manager would suggest this - I am using this Skit as part of a Reductio ad Absurdum)
There is nothing Unprofessional about raising doubts or challenging a bad idea. What can be unprofessional is the manner, time, place and forum that such challenges are made.
I will get to the flip-side as well in a minute.
A good rule of thumb is 'Praise in Public, Criticize in Private' - so let us go to our above example - I would ask to see my Boss and his boss in private and lay out my concerns with the plan (legality, Ethics, which department would be responsible etc.)
As part of that private conversation - I would try and present as much objective data as to why the idea is a bad idea.
The manner in which the critique is raise is also important - there is a difference between trying to come up with hypothetical solutions to problems with a bad idea and then leading the Management to it being unfeasible vs outright saying 'It won't work'
There are a number of other factors - but hopefully you get the Jist.
Now, onto the flipside - which is a company that will not tolerate robust debate around ideas. It is one thing to want to have such discussion away from lower-level employees so that their perception is not tainted - but it is entirely another to demand blind allegiance.
Again - I reference the above example of the comedy skit - sometimes the Good idea Fairy is, in fact, the Bad idea Fairy and needs to be dismissed - and if the company culture is such that even a bad idea cannot be challenged...
The company culture is Toxic
